# What is the use of WITH CHECK keyword

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
CHECK CONSTRAINT CK_Employee_BirthDate
```

when I run the above line of code I am not getting error.

But when I run below line of code I am getting error "**The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint**"

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT CK_Employee_BirthDate
```

Can anyone help me to understand what is the difference between using WITH CHECK and not using it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Comment: its in SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Nijith well just look at the docs for 2008, then!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Bogdan's comment, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx explains that the "WITH CHECK" syntax ensures that data in the table is validated against the new CHECK constraint. From that link, WITH CHECK is assumed for new constraints, but WITH NOCHECK is assumed when you re-enable an existing constraint:

```
 WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK

    Specifies whether the data in the table is or is not validated against a newly added or re-enabled FOREIGN KEY or CHECK constraint. If not specified, WITH CHECK is assumed for new constraints, and WITH NOCHECK is assumed for re-enabled constraints.

    If you do not want to verify new CHECK or FOREIGN KEY constraints against existing data, use WITH NOCHECK. We do not recommend doing this, except in rare cases. The new constraint will be evaluated in all later data updates. Any constraint violations that are suppressed by WITH NOCHECK when the constraint is added may cause future updates to fail if they update rows with data that does not comply with the constraint.

    The query optimizer does not consider constraints that are defined WITH NOCHECK. Such constraints are ignored until they are re-enabled by using ALTER TABLE table WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL.
```